# leaflet map and jquery mobile how fix the map

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I have spent a lot time finding and trying code for solution about, how display a map with leaflet and jquery mobile, but I can't  find a solution. I show a listview and when I click it, the map show a icon with lat,lon, but I get it.

Anybody can help me.

[image]

This is my code. I need you a response map.

```
    <style type="text/css">
#map { min-height: 320px; height: 100%; margin: -15px;}
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
html, body, {
height: 100%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

         <div data-role="page" id="glossary">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h3>Example</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' id='resultsList'>
                    <!-- keep empty for dynamically added items -->
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- display -->
        <div data-role="page" id="display">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h3>Name Goes Here</h3>
 <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
  <div id="definition"></div>
        <div id="weathermap"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>
var json ={"rows":[{"id":"129","id_user":"1","id_dispositivo":"1","Latitude":"10.1497326","Longitude":"-67.9283981"},{"id":"135","id_user":"1","id_dispositivo":"2","Latitude":"8.6119127","Longitude":"-70.2084732"}]};
            var currentItem = 0;
            $('#glossary').on('pageinit', function() {

                $.each(json.rows, function(i, term) {
$('#resultsList').append('<li><a href="#display"' + term.id_dispositivo + '"><img src="../menu0/images/dispositivos/small/'+term.id_dispositivo+'.jpg" height=100px width=100px/></a></li>')
                });
                $('#resultsList').listview('refresh');

                $('#resultsList li').click(function() {
                    currentItem = $(this).index();
                });
            });

            $('#display').on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
                $(this).find('[data-role=header] .ui-title').text(json.rows[currentItem].id_dispositivo);
var lat = json.rows[currentItem].Latitude;
var lon = json.rows[currentItem].Longitude;   
initMap(lat,lon);

            });



function initMap(lat,lon){
 document.getElementById('weathermap').innerHTML = "<div id='map' style='min-height: 320px; height: 100%; margin: -15px;'></div>";
var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup. <br> Easily customizable.')
.openPopup();
   }
</script>
```

I use this code because when I create a map I get a message map container is alreay initialized. whith it code show the map.

```
document.getElementById('weathermap').innerHTML = "<div id='map' style='min-height: 320px; height: 100%; margin: -15px;'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The style for the map container seems fine, so the problem might be coming from the height/width of

```
<div id="weathermap"></div>
```

or

```
<div data-role="page" id="display">
```

For example if the `div#weathermap` has a height of 200px, the map div that you append inside with `height: 100%;` will just be 200px at the end.

So you have to fine which one of these two divs are not taking the while page height (it might also be a problem on the body's height)